# stopping jquery countdown when the timer reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

hi i am using a jquery countdown timer in my project link of which is

[jquery countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)

i am writing the following code to initialize the timer

```
var fiveSeconds = new Date().getTime() + 5000;
$('#spanTimer').countdown(fiveSeconds, {elapse: true})
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (event.elapsed) {
            $this.html(event.strftime('After end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
        } else {
            $this.html(event.strftime('To end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
        }
    });
```

the timer is set for 05 seconds or what ever seconds i pass into it. the problem i am having is that i am unable to stop the timer when it reaches 00:00:00. i mean it resets. what am i doing wrong? how can i get an alert that timer has reached 00:00:00? i am new to jquery countdown.

Comment: Take off the `{elapse: true}` ?  From docs: `elapse:     '{bool} Allow to continue after finishes'`

Comment: Otherwise there are various methods you can use: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#controls

Comment: I tried doing this in if (event.elapsed) but not working...@Taplar

Comment: @Taplar thank you very much for responding so quickly. you saved my day... i was trying to remove {elapse:true} inside if statement. which was wrong.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the elapsed: true, and use the finished.countdown callback. It's kind of what it's there for. And read the manual, very very well written.

Note that I don't need to know the value of the timer, the on('finish.countdown' ...) makes all that transparent to me. If finish.countdown is fired off, then I know the timer reached zero.

```js
var fiveSeconds = new Date().getTime() + 5000;
$('#spanTimer').countdown(fiveSeconds)
    // removed the elapsed: true
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (event.elapsed) {
            $this.html(event.strftime('After end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
        } else {
            $this.html(event.strftime('To end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
        }
    })
    // added a finish.countdown callback, to
    //  hide the countdown altogether and
    //  have a little fun.
    .on('finish.countdown', function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $("#boomRoom").show();
    });
```

```css
#boomRoom {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<div id="spanTimer">
</div>
<div id="boomRoom">
  <img src="http://bestanimations.com/Military/Explosions/atomic-mushroom-cloud-explosion-2-2.gif"/>
  </div>
```